# for loop exits early

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am working on a version of the Fifteen Puzzle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle), using html and javascript (no JQuery). To work out the basic functionality, I have set up a 9 x 9 grid. I have eight 100 x 100 px colored images (id=box1 through box8) and one 100 x 100 px white or "empty" box (boxW). These are the nine tiles in my grid. I have figured out how to move an adjacent image tile into the empty tile and how to highlight the border of a tile that is moveable. Now I am trying to create a function that will shuffle the tiles at the start of play. I pick a random box and see if it is moveable by comparing its margins to the margins of the empty tile. If so, I move it and repeat. The problem is my for-loop seems to exit after only a few moves - sometimes 1, sometimes 20, but never 100 or 500 or 1000, regardless of the upper limit I have set for the loop. I have set up an admin feature to print out what is happening. I have tried adding "continue" at different points under the assumption that something about my "if" statements is kicking it out of the loop but that does not seem to help. I'm sure I am missing something obvious but I can't see it. (By the way, "tileHold" is an attempt to avoid reversing the last move.) Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my function as well as an example of the admin output:

```
    function shuffle(){
    var tileHold=boxW;
    for(var i=1;i<1000;i++){
        var tile = "box"+(Math.round(Math.random() * 8));
        if (tile != tileHold){
            var toppx = document.getElementById(tile).style.marginTop;
            var leftpx =document.getElementById(tile).style.marginLeft;
            var top = toppx.substring(0,3);
            var left = leftpx.substring(0,3);
            var topWpx = document.getElementById("boxW").style.marginTop; 
            var leftWpx = document.getElementById("boxW").style.marginLeft;
            var topW = topWpx.substring(0,3);
            var leftW = leftWpx.substring(0,3);
            if (((top===topW) && ((Math.abs(left-leftW))<200)) || ((left===leftW) && ((Math.abs(top-topW))<200))) {
                document.getElementById(tile).style.marginTop = topWpx;
                document.getElementById(tile).style.marginLeft = leftWpx;
                document.getElementById("boxW").style.marginTop = toppx;
                document.getElementById("boxW").style.marginLeft = leftpx;
                document.getElementById("guess_2").innerHTML = guess_2.innerHTML+tile+" <br />";
            }
            document.getElementById("guess_2").innerHTML = guess_2.innerHTML+tile+" i="+ i+ " <br />";
        }
        tileHold=tile;
    }

}
```

And here's the sample output, including the tile that was moved (e.g. box7) and the loop cycle. This time, there were eleven loops before exiting. As you can see, the upper limit of the loop is 1000.

```
Admin box7 i=1 
box6 
box6 i=2 
box2 i=4 
box5 
box5 i=5 
box7 i=6 
box6 i=7 
box3 i=8 
box1 i=10 
box6 i=11
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? may be thats the reason its exiting

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Just run this under a debugger. So many things can go wrong in your code. Specifically, the substring calls you do may be over strings that are less than 3 characters. Also, you should not be subtracting two strings from each other, look at `Math.abs(left-leftW)` for example. You are passing the result of subtraction of 2 strings to the absolute function. You shuold first convert the values to Numbers and then check the difference.

Comment: No errors. I tried setting up a jsfiddle but can't get it to run there. Added parseInt to convert my strings. Thanks for these suggestions. No luck so far.

Comment: Okay, I figured out one major issue with my code. I named my images box1, box2, box3 etc and then I was picking a random box with the following code 
    
    var tile = "box"+(Math.round(Math.random() * 8));

The problem was this would sometimes produce a "box0" and I had not created a "box0"! So I renumbered my boxes from 0-7 and changed the constant in my code to 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take into account that the code inside the first if will be executed 999-n times (since you are starting in 1), where n is the number of times "tile" becomes equal to "tileHold" so if you want the code inside that if to be executed exactly 1000 times you need to modify your code like this:

```
.
.
.
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){       
    while(true){
       var tile = "box"+(Math.round(Math.random() * 8));
       if(tile!=tileHold) break;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Also take into account that the second if will be executed only when:

```
 (((top===topW) && ((Math.abs(left-leftW))<200)) || ((left===leftW)
```

becomes true. So, if what you want is this code to be executed exaclty 1000 times you need to modify your function as follows:

```
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
    while(true){
       var tile = "box"+(Math.round(Math.random() * 8));
       if(tile==tileHold) continue;
       var toppx = document.getElementById(tile).style.marginTop;
       var leftpx =document.getElementById(tile).style.marginLeft;
       var top = toppx.substring(0,3);
       var left = leftpx.substring(0,3);
       var topWpx = document.getElementById("boxW").style.marginTop; 
       var leftWpx = document.getElementById("boxW").style.marginLeft;
       var topW = topWpx.substring(0,3);
       var leftW = leftWpx.substring(0,3);
       if(((top===topW) && ((Math.abs(left-leftW))<200)) || ((left===leftW) && ((Math.abs(top-topW))<200))) break;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will review this carefully and make appropriate changes to my code. I also just figured out that part of my problem had to do with my id's and the math.round function.